# How to add image on the sides of a QSlider

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qslider

I have redesigned and implemented a QSlider using its Stylesheets.

I could not find how to place an image before and after (left or right, top or bottom) the slider itself though.

Ex:

Slider:

```
----00---------------
```

Image Left:

```
qqqqq
```

Image Right:

```
ddddd
```

Result:

```
qqqqq----00---------------ddddd
```

I am currently using a QHBoxLayout and insert these images using QLabels but it does not seem like the right or the best way.

How can I else add these images correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some ASCII art showing how the result should look like? Something like `----qqqqq00ddddd---------------`?

Comment: Hello @doc. I've already done it. It's the 3rd row "Result:" Basically: Image_A + Slider Itself + Image_B.

Comment: Using a `QHBoxLayout` is the cleanest and simplest. Why do you think that this wouldn't be the right way?

Comment: Hello @DK. The original QSlider comes with 3 body parts + the handle. So I assumed stylesheets would allow to change them, instead of me implying it via layouts as a new widget, which I already have done. If this is the only way, I will close the question. Please confirm, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve that with only style sheets and the `border-image` property on the `groove` subcontrol.

For example with a border image like this:

[image: Slider decoration image]

To better see what goes where, B is 10 pixel wide, the space is 2, and A is 12 pixel wide.

```css
QSlider::groove {      
   border-image: url(:/slider-decoration.png) 0 12 0 10;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 12px solid transparent;
}
QSlider::handle {
    width: 8px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Which gives you what you expect:

[image: resulting slider]

This solution has a small problem, though. The mouse ignores the presence of the border, and there is an offset near both ends between the handle position and the mouse position. 
So, to avoid that, the handle has to go all the way to either side, but we add a transparent border to it that make it look like it stops just before the image borders:

```css
QSlider::groove {      
   border-image: url(:/slider-decoration.png) 0 12 0 10;
   border-left: 10px;
   border-right: 12px;
}
QSlider::handle {
    width: 8px;
    /* add borders to the handle that will sit above the groove border */
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;       

    /* negative margins to allow the handle borders 
       to go past the groove borders */
    margin-right: -10px;    
    margin-left: -12px;
    background-color: green;
    /* make the background color fill the content, not the border */
    background-clip: content;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you @alexisdm! One quick question though. Does this also apply for HTML and CSS3 or is this awesomeness Qt specific? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @Phil You should be able do the same thing with at least WebKit browsers (safari, chrome, and QtWebKit): [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3vv/). IE doesn't support border-image, and FF, doesn't support sliders (html5 input range).

Comment: alexisdm, this has really been good useful info. thanks again and again. cheers ;-)

Comment: What about putting different images to border-image? you can correct me if i am wrong. In your way you are putting the same images into both sides?

Comment: @Alper The border image is a single image that will be sliced into 9 parts (the 4 numbers are the top, right, bottom and left coordinates of the cuts, here there is only 3 parts since top and bottom are 0). So if you want a different image at each side, you must concatenate all the images into that single image.

Answer (score 1):

The three "body parts" of the slider are the `groove`, `add-page`, and `sub-page`. All of these are actually within the bounds of the `QSlider`, so styling gives you an effect like [the one in this blog post](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/03/10/fancy-qslider-stylesheet/). Using stylesheets will give you the effect:

```
qqqq00ddddddddddddddd
```

instead of

```
qqqqq----00---------------ddddd
```

which you can achieve by simply sticking with your `QHBoxLayout` strategy.